# Vector values not in inserting order

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm inserting values into a vector:
    `vector<map<vector<string> , vector<string> > > listedParameterMap;`

like this:
    `listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);`

If I check later the vector, the order is inverted.
Did I miss something?

**EDIT:**
I think it may be somewhere else... I just got an idea. But I'll try tomorrow.
I almost had today aleady at least one brain-stackoverflow with my code ;)

Anyway thank you all for helping. I'll tell if somthing changes!

**EDIT2:**
Seems like the error is somewhere else. I just could see where it happens, but until now not why. On a point where the map should get filled just once, it gets filled twice.
For some reason each time only on a specific value. That's why it was looking like the values are inverted.
If I need some help I'll open a new question. 
Thanks to everyone!

---

**UPDATE:**

The vector is ok now. Found the problem. Blindness of own code ;)

It doen't influence my programm my the map is inverted.
I just created a new map inserting and then printing the values, this works then as expected.

Comment: listedParameterMap is a vector not a map.

Comment: sorry... I started writting something wrong -> corrected

Comment: Why do you write `listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), 1, parameterMap);`? I feel it's the same as `listedParameterMap.insert(listedParameterMap.end(), parameterMap);`.

Comment: We need to see more code, and we need to know what you are expecting for output, and what you are getting.

Comment: I don't think this code is explaining the whole story since what's written here should work.

Comment: The underlying question seems to be: why does `vec.insert(vec.end(), item)` produce a different order to `vec.push_back(item)` - I'm not sure what the answer is either.

Comment: Since you didn't show any code, how can anybody point to your error? You aren't trying to say that vector implementation is wrong, I hope.

Comment: I'm comming from Java. I thought maybe there is some secret here ;)

Comment: Either accept the answer that helped you the most, or add your own detailing what was actually wrong, so that people with the same situation will be helped by what you learned.

Comment: @Will ok than I accept an answer. It wasn't anything special. I was looking at the wrong place. The map is inverted not the vector. That's strange too but doesn't affenct my result, that's why I won't care about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you simply write:

```
listedParameterMap.push_back(parameterMap);
```

It's simpler interface than what you're doing in your post.

Comment: @Beasly, then what made you stop trying it, what errors or unexpected behaviour did you see?

Comment: Even though I agree that he should do this.  It doesn't really address the issue, since his call to insert should work just the same.

Answer (score 2):

I can't make much sense of your sample code, but if you want to insert items into a vector in order, you usually want to use `push_back`. For a trivial example:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    numbers.push_back(i);
```

The numbers should now be in order, like: (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).

Comment: Even if, in your example, you were to use `numbers.insert(numbers.end(), i)` you would get the same answer. It's a bit more cumbersome, but it doesn't seem like that's the problem.

Comment: @Andrew Noyes: In theory you're right. If he uses `insert` exactly correctly, the elements should end up in order -- but the code is pretty fragile and easy to get wrong (and if he was using it that way, we'd never have seen the question). With `push_back` it's essentially impossible to mess things up.

Comment: I can agree that it's more likely for someone to make a programming error this way, but his code is correct so the actual problem is probably the same using either method, so I don't think this problem would go away.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you want to do a map that uses a vector as a key, do you? This smells like you have more significant design problems.

As for adding stuff to vectors in a known (and presered order), use push_back().

Comment: Yes I want... I have some requirements where I need it.

Comment: There are much more efficient ways of doing it - eg. storing your key vector elsewhere, and using a unique id (eg. int values) as the key values in your map. ie. analogous to the approach used in an RDBMS.

Comment: You need a vector of maps, each of which maps a vector of strings to another vector of strings? That's an "interesting" design!